# Internet Explorer CSS issue on Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer

This page looks fine in Opera, Firefox and Chrome:

http://pt.drpedrocoelho.com/contactos

But try it out in IE and it shows the map above and the form below (grrr...).

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What version of IE? it looks fine in IE 9.

Comment: I'm using IE8. Does it show up to you or someone else's IE8? A friend of mine also has IE8 and it shows up to him like that.

Comment: if you follor W3C conventions your site will work in any navigator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and easy fix would be to float:right the paragraph tag that the map iframe is in.

Comment: Thank you. That worked.

I wrapped the map with this:

<p style="float: right;">iframe google map here</p>

Hope that helps someone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

follow the W3C conventions http://validator.w3.org/
also you can install a firefox plugin of w3c to get supported

Comment: This is a wordpress installation. How would I do that, and would that fix the IE fix?